# Finding dependency issues in yocto do_rootfs() activity

Tags: dependencies, yocto, bitbake

I'm looking for some help to figure out how to troubleshoot a problem I'm having with yocto. I'm taking an existing yocto metadata setup and porting it from qt4 to qt5. The old setup was done by someone much better at this than I am, and I'm muddling my way though. I do know enough to understand most of the concepts. Where I'm stuck is the following.

```
ERROR: fitcore3-image-dev-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Unable to install packages. Command '/home/pete/builds/fitcore3/yocto/build/tmp/work/fitcore3-poky-linux-gnueabi/fitcore3-image-dev/1.0-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/opkg --volatile-cache -f /home/pete/builds/fitcore3/yocto/build/tmp/work/fitcore3-poky-linux-gnueabi/fitcore3-image-dev/1.0-r0/opkg.conf -t /home/pete/builds/fitcore3/yocto/build/tmp/work/fitcore3-poky-linux-gnueabi/fitcore3-image-dev/1.0-r0/temp/ipktemp/ -o /home/pete/builds/fitcore3/yocto/build/tmp/work/fitcore3-poky-linux-gnueabi/fitcore3-image-dev/1.0-r0/rootfs  --force_postinstall --prefer-arch-to-version   install opkg packagegroup-core-boot packagegroup-fitcore3-base packagegroup-fitcore3-bit packagegroup-fitcore3-debug packagegroup-fitcore3-non-release packagegroup-fitcore3-se4 run-postinsts' returned 2:
Collected errors:
 * Solver encountered 2 problem(s):
 * Problem 1/2:
 *   - package packagegroup-fitcore3-base-1.0-r0.all requires bsdsdaemon, but none of the providers can be installed
 * 
 * Solution 1:
 *   - do not ask to install a package providing packagegroup-fitcore3-base

 * Problem 2/2:
 *   - package packagegroup-fitcore3-bit-1.0-r0.all requires audio, but none of the providers can be installed
 * 
 * Solution 1:
 *   - do not ask to install a package providing packagegroup-fitcore3-bit

 * opkg_finalize_intercepts: Failed to open dir /home/pete/builds/fitcore3/yocto/build/tmp/work/fitcore3-poky-linux-gnueabi/fitcore3-image-dev/1.0-r0/temp/ipktemp//opkg-ossjWY/opkg-intercept-gKnz7M: No such file or directory.
 * rm_r: Failed to open dir /home/pete/builds/fitcore3/yocto/build/tmp/work/fitcore3-poky-linux-gnueabi/fitcore3-image-dev/1.0-r0/temp/ipktemp//opkg-ossjWY/opkg-intercept-gKnz7M: No such file or directory.
 * rm_r: Failed to open dir /home/pete/builds/fitcore3/yocto/build/tmp/work/fitcore3-poky-linux-gnueabi/fitcore3-image-dev/1.0-r0/temp/ipktemp//opkg-ossjWY: No such file or directory.

ERROR: fitcore3-image-dev-1.0-r0 do_rootfs: Function failed: do_rootfs
```

I think this is an opkg dependency issue caused by a package missing in my RDEPENDS for my package lists for my rootfs. My problem is, I don't know how to figure out which package is missing from that list (it's not mesa, this is a framebuffer need, and I took out wayland and x11). The two listed packages in the error report are mine, and I have metadata that include REDEPENDS = "qtbase" for qt5 plus all other known RDEPENDS. All packages compile successfully and I have .ipk's for all of them as well. I expect this is a qt5 dependency I'm not meeting, but Google won't tell me what that is.

Looking at the dot files isn't helping, though I was able to remove some unneeded stuff doing that. I still haven't found the culprit.

Can anyone provide me some insight into what's the best way to diagnose this problem?

Comment: you seem to be missing a meta layer

Comment: I looked, but I don't see a way to know if that's the issue. I did remove at qt4 layer, and a hardware layer we don't use (rockchip, which was obsoleted). How would I diagnose that as a problem?

Comment: do you have recipes for those packages in included layers?

Comment: Yes, I can build them normally, and when I build my image, it builds all the packages as expected. I found a reference to a RPi problem that was nearly identical which called out a missing sub dependency (related to X). So I think I need to find a missing qtbase dependency with something similar. Like, DISTRO_FEATUES removes "x11", but qtbase depends on something X11 provides but can't be installed. At least that's my theory right now.